# explain behavior of accept function when is called on active socket (instead of passive socket)

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a text book TCP server. In which I am using accept function on an active socket. Note: I have commented out the call to listen on listenfd in main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void do_work(int sockfd, int lisfd)
{
    printf("Child's process id is %d\n", getpid());
    close(lisfd);
    const int MAXLINE = 30;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;
    ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
    write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}

//argc and argv include the program name itself too in the count and array 
int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    const int IPLEN = 50;
    //max number of connections that server can handle simultaneously
    const int LISTENQ = 10;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    char cliip[IPLEN];
    socklen_t len;
    const int PORT = 8088;

    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ) < 0)
    {
        printf("listenning socket error %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    //initialize sockaddr stuctures to zero
    bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    //initialize value-result argument to accept
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    // INADDR_ANY means that socket bound to this servaddr can accept connection
    // from any of the interface available on the system
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("bind error %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    //listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    printf("Parent's process id is %d\n", getpid());

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    //for(;;)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
        printf("accepting connection from ip %s on port %lu\n",
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, &cliip, sizeof(cliip)), ntohl(cliaddr.sin_port));
        pid_t childpid;
        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            do_work(connfd,listenfd);
        }
        // if you don't close it here, then connfd shall remain open in parent process and EOF shall not be issued as FIN segment shall not be sent by tcp
        close(connfd); 
    }
}
```

Now when I connect to it through a simple client, it gives me an output like this.

```
Parent's process id is 11145
accepting connection from ip 0.0.0.0 on port 0
accepting connection from ip 0.0.0.0 on port 0
Child's process id is 11146
Child's process id is 11147
```

What I want to understand is: what does 0.0.0.0 means here? (Google says that this means that there is no tcp/ip connection here.) But I am not able to put it into perspective. Any help please?

Comment: Your text book is outdated. Please consider updating to a newer `IPv6` friendly one. It's such small simple things like using `sockaddr_storage` instead of `sockaddr_in` that makes all the difference! :)

Comment: Yes!! I totally agree to that.!! :) But thanks anyways to point it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most propably the call to `accept()` failed.

You shall test whether `accept()` returned `-1` prior to looking into `cliaddr`.

---

<strike>Also the code you show `close()`es the listing socket (down in `do_Work()`) after the first `accept()`. Any following `accept()` though will surely fail.</strike><sup>I missed the call to `fork()`</sup>

---

As per *[Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63743/duck)*'s comment:

However as long as the call to `listen()` is commented out `accept()` has to fail.

Comment: Most likely EINVAL Socket is not listening for connections

Comment: Btwn alk, as you pointed out, "Also the code you show close()es the listing socket (down in do_Work()) after the first accept(). Any following accept() though will surely fail." At first glance. Even I thought that You are right on this one. But my server is accepting the requests alright. Can you try to explain that behavior too?

Comment: @Tyagi Akhilesh, easily.  do_work() is done by the child which inherits a copy of the open descriptors so closing the listening socket does not affect the parent's open descriptor.  Likewise the parent immediately closes the connfd, a copy of which the child uses to send data, but this causes not damage and is indeed wise. alk was incorrect on this point.

Comment: @Duck Thought so :) Thanks for putting in the words. I suppose the key words are "Copy of open descriptors"